# What is the meaning of "doctor jail"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of that and why is said that way?

I read it on a title that says: Becky Lynch's journey from "doctor jail" to WWE TLC

I'm sure that people that is not from the U.S. can't understand the meaning of "doctor jail".

Comment: Did you watch the 24 minute video available on youtube called from doctor jail to something something? I can only find references to Becky Lynch's journey.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I think now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Whilst this at first seemed a very simple need to explain a term I was not familiar with, it illustrates a much more profound shift in language .See my conclusion below.

It appears that in this case Becky Lynch tweeted Nov 18, 2018

"Everyone writing love letters to each other on social media about #SurvivorSeries tonight. Well here’s my statement: I cannot wait to get out of **doctor jail** and rip all your faces off. Signed, The Man."

This was a reference to an incident described [here](https://www.sportskeeda.com/wwe/wwe-news-becky-lynch-gives-her-thoughts-on-tonight-s-survivor-series)
"Becky Lynch was injured at the hands of Nia Jax during a SmackDown Live Women's invasion angle to conclude Monday Night RAW. This left the little "Lasskicker" with a bloody, broken nose and a severe concussion. The following day on SmackDown Live, it was confirmed by WWE officials that Becky Lynch would not be able to compete at Survivor Series."

Thus she was barred from participating until she was medically cleared to return to action.

A similar common term on that social media is "Twitter jail" see these [2011](https://twitter.com/CuddlyCoreyHugs/status/138436123574796290) [references](https://blog.bufferapp.com/twitter-jail)

The etymology is not clear as **previously "Doctor jail"** similar to ["Teacher jail"](https://www.thenation.com/article/where-shame-policy-inside-las-teacher-jail/) was traditionally applied to a professional worker (possibly still on pay or leave) who was required to stand down from duty i.e. in those cases **The Doctor is barred from work**.

What we see here is the power of social media to produce a [paradigm shift](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paradigm%20shift) in the use of language since the pair of "person jail" formerly implied the subject group of people who were barred, **now** on social media it is considered the subject is the one who is the goaler. So in this case it is no longer the "doctor" who is considered "in jail" but now the "doctor" is the one who does the jailing.